# How do I run a command as another user?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I’m using the following version of Linux

```
[me@ip-99-99-99-99 myproject]$ uname -a
Linux ip-99-99-99-99 99.99.99-99.99.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 14 23:20:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I’m having difficulty running a command as another user.  Note below I’m able to run the “gradle build” command as my user (despite the fact it fails).  However, when I try and run it as a different user, I get a “gradle not found” error.  What am I doing wrong below?

```
[me@ip-99-99-99-99 myproject]$ gradle build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type TaskArtifactStateCacheAccess using TaskExecutionServices.createCacheAccess().
> Failed to create parent directory '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/jenkins/jobs/myproject/workspace/myproject/.gradle/2.8' when creating directory '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/jenkins/jobs/   myproject/workspace/myproject/.gradle/2.8/taskArtifacts'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.301 secs
[me@ip-99-99-99-99 myproject]$ sudo -H -u tomcat bash -c 'gradle build'
bash: gradle: command not found
```

Comment: If you actually want to run a shell or command as another user, the `su` (switch user) command is what you are looking for. run `su <username>` in a shell, provide that users password, and the shell will be running as the user requested. you can use the command `whoami` to test this. When you are finished, use Ctrl + C to "logout" of the shell, and return to one running under your own user.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the 'gradle' command is not found in the path. As your me account try 'which gradle' to get a path to the command. Then on the sudo command specify the full path to gradle.

(would have added this as a comment, but rep not high enough- sorry).